# API de Dicionário em Java

Tags: java, api, dicionário

Olá, procuro uma API, de dicionário, em Java para criar o programa nos seguintes passos:

- Usuário entra com uma string, no caso, uma palavra;
- Imprimo na tela a invocação de um método dessa API;
- O qual retornará uma frase, com o significado da palavra que o usuário digitou em questão;

> **Exemplo**: entro com a palavra "bolo", e receberei na tela o seu
>   significado.

Gostaria que essa possível API suportasse múltiplos idiomas.

Answer (score 3):

Pelo que entendi você quer uma API para fazer chamados em dicionários correto?

**JWNL** (usa  a base de dados da [Java WordNet Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordNet) que é majoritariamente em ingles, existem versões em outras línguas)

> http://sourceforge.net/projects/jwordnet/

exemplo de código:

```
/** A class to demonstrate the functionality of the JWNL package. */
public class Examples {
    private static final String USAGE = "java Examples <properties file>";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.out.println(USAGE);
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        String propsFile = args[0];
        try {
            // initialize JWNL (this must be done before JWNL can be used)
            JWNL.initialize(new FileInputStream(propsFile));
            new Examples().go();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }

    private IndexWord ACCOMPLISH;
    private IndexWord DOG;
    private IndexWord CAT;
    private IndexWord FUNNY;
    private IndexWord DROLL;
    private String MORPH_PHRASE = "running-away";

    public Examples() throws JWNLException {
        ACCOMPLISH = Dictionary.getInstance().getIndexWord(POS.VERB, "accomplish");
        DOG = Dictionary.getInstance().getIndexWord(POS.NOUN, "dog");
        CAT = Dictionary.getInstance().lookupIndexWord(POS.NOUN, "cat");
        FUNNY = Dictionary.getInstance().lookupIndexWord(POS.ADJECTIVE, "funny");
        DROLL = Dictionary.getInstance().lookupIndexWord(POS.ADJECTIVE, "droll");
    }

    public void go() throws JWNLException {
        demonstrateMorphologicalAnalysis(MORPH_PHRASE);
        demonstrateListOperation(ACCOMPLISH);
        demonstrateTreeOperation(DOG);
        demonstrateAsymmetricRelationshipOperation(DOG, CAT);
        demonstrateSymmetricRelationshipOperation(FUNNY, DROLL);
    }

    private void demonstrateMorphologicalAnalysis(String phrase) throws JWNLException {
        // "running-away" is kind of a hard case because it involves
        // two words that are joined by a hyphen, and one of the words
        // is not stemmed. So we have to both remove the hyphen and stem
        // "running" before we get to an entry that is in WordNet
        System.out.println("Base form for \"" + phrase + "\": " +
                           Dictionary.getInstance().lookupIndexWord(POS.VERB, phrase));
    }

    private void demonstrateListOperation(IndexWord word) throws JWNLException {
        // Get all of the hypernyms (parents) of the first sense of <var>word</var>
        PointerTargetNodeList hypernyms = PointerUtils.getInstance().getDirectHypernyms(word.getSense(1));
        System.out.println("Direct hypernyms of \"" + word.getLemma() + "\":");
        hypernyms.print();
    }

    private void demonstrateTreeOperation(IndexWord word) throws JWNLException {
        // Get all the hyponyms (children) of the first sense of <var>word</var>
        PointerTargetTree hyponyms = PointerUtils.getInstance().getHyponymTree(word.getSense(1));
        System.out.println("Hyponyms of \"" + word.getLemma() + "\":");
        hyponyms.print();
    }

    private void demonstrateAsymmetricRelationshipOperation(IndexWord start, IndexWord end) throws JWNLException {
        // Try to find a relationship between the first sense of <var>start</var> and the first sense of <var>end</var>
        RelationshipList list = RelationshipFinder.getInstance().findRelationships(start.getSense(1), end.getSense(1), PointerType.HYPERNYM);
        System.out.println("Hypernym relationship between \"" + start.getLemma() + "\" and \"" + end.getLemma() + "\":");
        for (Iterator itr = list.iterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
            ((Relationship) itr.next()).getNodeList().print();
        }
        System.out.println("Common Parent Index: " + ((AsymmetricRelationship) list.get(0)).getCommonParentIndex());
        System.out.println("Depth: " + ((Relationship) list.get(0)).getDepth());
    }

    private void demonstrateSymmetricRelationshipOperation(IndexWord start, IndexWord end) throws JWNLException {
        // find all synonyms that <var>start</var> and <var>end</var> have in common
        RelationshipList list = RelationshipFinder.getInstance().findRelationships(start.getSense(1), end.getSense(1), PointerType.SIMILAR_TO);
        System.out.println("Synonym relationship between \"" + start.getLemma() + "\" and \"" + end.getLemma() + "\":");
        for (Iterator itr = list.iterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
            ((Relationship) itr.next()).getNodeList().print();
        }
        System.out.println("Depth: " + ((Relationship) list.get(0)).getDepth());
    }
}
```